# How insert enum as int in DynamoDb with ServiceStack.Aws

Tags: c#, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb

i have a model that has a enum property and i need save this model with this property in DynamoDb, but as integer rather than string (default behavior in ServiceStack.Aws).

In ServiceStack.DataAnnotations's namespace there is an attribute "EnumAsInt". I put this attribute in my model, but don't work. Currently, i get an error that say that my index expected an integer but i sent a string value.

My model looks like this

```
[References(typeof(PersonContactIndex))]
    [Alias("PersonContact")]
    public class PersonContact
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int PersonContactId { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [EnumAsInt]
        public PersonContactType ContactType { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    }
```

My index looks like this

```
public class PersonContactIndex: IGlobalIndex<PersonContact>
    {
        [HashKey]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [RangeKey]
        [EnumAsInt]
        public PersonContactType ContactType { get; set; }

        public int PersonContactId { get; set; }
    }
```

Another way could be setting up a custom converter that AWSSDK support, but i don't know if ServiceStack has the logic to call to this converter before send the query to DynamoDB

So, how can i save my enums as int in DynamoDb with ServiceStack.Aws ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added support configurable Enum Types in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/commit/abd5ad3f2da494507489d48ac4c55bf7248234b1) which follows the same behavior as OrmLite and ServiceStack.Text text serializers where Enum's are serialized by strings by default unless:

The default behavior of Enums is changed with the global configuration:

```
JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = true;
```

It's a Flag Enum:

```
[Flags] 
enum SuitsFlags 
{ 
    Spades = 1, 
    Clubs = 2, 
    Diamonds = 4, 
    Hearts = 8 
}
```

Or the enum is annotated with `[EnumAsInt]`, e.g:

```
[EnumAsInt]
enum Suits 
{ 
    Spades, 
    Clubs, 
    Diamonds, 
    Hearts 
}
```

You can also customize how each value is converted by registering a custom value converter implementing [IAttributeValueConverter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/abd5ad3f2da494507489d48ac4c55bf7248234b1/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/IAttributeValueConverter.cs#L13), e.g:

```
DynamoMetadata.Converters.ValueConverters[typeof(Suits)] = 
    new MySuitsEnumConverter();
```

The `[EnumAsInt]` is only meant to annotate enum types which is now what it's restricted to.

This change is available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).